# duplicate key error on relationship of foreign key on multiple tables

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, factory-boy

I am trying to insert data to a table which has an ID that maps to another table and I expect it to create data required for my relationship... The problem is that within the Parent, I have another relation, and in the Child, I also relate to the Child from the parent... See below:

```
class Parent(Base):
    parent_field = Column(Integer)
    childa_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(ChildATable.childa_id))
    childb_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(ChildBTable.childb_id))

    childa = relationship(ChildATable)
    childb = relationship(ChildBTable)


class ChildA(Base):
    childa_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    childb_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(ChildB.childb_id))


class ChildB(Base):
    childb_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)


class ParentTable(factory.alchemy.SQLAlchemyModelFactory)
    class Meta:
        ....

    parent_field = factory.Sequence(lambda n: n + 1)
    childa = factory.SubFactory(ChildA)
    childb = factory.SubFactory(ChildB)

class ChildATable(factory.alchemy.SQLAlchemyModelFactory)
    class Meta:
        ....

    childa_id = factory.Sequence(lambda n: n + 1)
    childb = factory.SubFactory(ChildB)

class ChildBTable(factory.alchemy.SQLAlchemyModelFactory)
    class Meta:
        ....

    childb_id = 1 #I need this to be hardcoded to 1
```

The problem is that when I use factory to insert Parent, apparently it tries to insert childb table twice given it's referenced in parent and childa, because I keep getting duplicate key for childb_id... ANy idea how to prevent this of happening?

The way I create the factory is by creating a Parent object and committing the session:

```
Parent()
Session.commit()
```

Comment: How do you "use factory to insert Parent"? Can you post the factories for Parent and ChildA?

Comment: I have modiefied the question with your request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the hood, your call to `ParentTable()` will translate to:

1. Call `ChildATable()`
2. Within `ChildATable()`, call `ChildBTable()`
3. Call `ChildBTable()` again, this time from `ParentTable()`

If you want your two factories to use the same `ChildB()` object, you could alter your `ParentTable()` factory as follows:

```
class ParentTable(factory.alchemy.SQLAlchemyModelFactory)
    class Meta:
        ....

    parent_field = factory.Sequence(lambda n: n + 1)
    childa = factory.SubFactory(ChildA,
        # Forward our `childb` to the `ChildA()` factory
        childb=factory.SelfAttribute('..childb'),
    )
    childb = factory.SubFactory(ChildB)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're getting the same number for `n` in the two subfactories. Can you try something like this?

```
class ParentTable(factory.alchemy.SQLAlchemyModelFactory)
    class Meta:
        ....

    parent_field = factory.Sequence(lambda n: 2*n + 1)
    childa = factory.SubFactory(ChildA)
    childb = factory.SubFactory(ChildB)
```